# RenderAsPdf failing in background service

Tags: serenity-platform

Im facing a similar issue as this: https://github.com/volkanceylan/Serenity/issues/2819#issuecomment-339887478

But the fix does not work with Asp.Net core version. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

With .net core version you can use Dependency

!!! Add `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;` on top

[image]

Comment: Thank you :)
However the context (ctx) is null when I'm calling RenderAsPdf from a background task. If I hard code the external URL my PDF generates, but it is a render of a permission denied error. I have impersonated admin before the RenderAsPdf, and the GitHub issue mentions passing a context but I'm absolutely stuck.

If I remove all the permission checks from the report controller and the row it generates OK. But naturally I can't have it open like that :(

Comment: you might need to remove cookie code and get url in appsetting (remove dependence on ctx)